# Unable to join static file to root directory in Django

Tags: python, django, django-settings

To join the static file in Django,

```
STATIC_URL = "os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')"

print("static file : ", (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')), )
```

This is producing :

```
static file :  C:/static
```

But in the same document I had joined template folder:
`print("Path is : ",  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject/template'))`

Which produces this: `Path is :  C:\Users\user\Desktop\django\myproject\myproject/template`

Is this the reason Django is producing this error:

```
ERRORS:
?: (urls.E006) The STATIC_URL setting must end with a slash.
```

Could you please advise how can i resolve this error?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Thanks for your comment. I have made the change to `STATIC_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')` and `print(STATIC_URL)` still prints `c:/static/` and the get request is : `"GET /C:/static/myproject/images/test.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1840`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

`STATIC_URL` is the path on your website url.

`STATIC_ROOT` is the path on your server where static files are located.

Comment: One would need to create `STATIC_ROOT` in `setting.py`?

Comment: I ask because just above `STATIC_URL` it says `# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)` So i was wondering if the path needs to be of `STATIC_URL` or `STATIC_ROOT`?